Python tkinter How to make a button that calls a function in a class
I'm doing a simple calculator in python and I'm wondering if it is possible to make a button that calls a function in a class.
from tkinter import*

l1 = []
l2 = []

root = Tk()

class przycisk:
    global liczba1
    def __init__(self, przy , text, row, column):
        self.przy = przy
        self.text = text
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

    def przycisk(self):
        self.przy = Button(root, text=f"{self.text}",
                           command=self.przy.liczba1)
        self.przy.grid(row = self.row, column = self.column, padx=2, pady=2)

    
    def liczba1(self):
        if bool(l1) == False:
            l1.insert[int(self.text)]


p1 = przycisk("p1" ,text = 1,row = 0,column = 0)
p1.przycisk()

I have tried to run it but it pops up this error:
 command=self.przy.liczba1)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'liczba1'

I'm expecting it to insert 1 into the list l1.

You meant to write: command=self.liczba1)

btw, what do you want self.przy to mean? In the __init__() method it gets the string "p1", but in the przycisk() method you overwrite it with the Button that you create.

Thanks it worked and i'm still learning so i thought i need a button to be = to a variable

Yes, but normally it is it's own variable: eg. self.button = Button(...
